# How to create a random changing paragraph with fade effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a horror themed website I'm supposed to create a `div` that houses reviews.

I want the reviews to stay on screen for a couple of seconds before fading out and being replaced with another review. I kind of have an idea about how to get the desired effect using `Jquery` and `absolute` css placement, but I'm having trouble getting the code to do exactly what I want.

Some examples on google and this website have pushed me to the right direction I think, but none work very well for multiple paragraphs + random placement. (In case a visitor returns to the site, he's faced with different reviews the the last time)

I'm guessing I'll need an array..

```js
$('#leftReview').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
```

```css
#ReviewContainer{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;

}

.leftReview{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;   
}
```

```html
<div id="ReviewContainer">
  <div class="leftReview">
    <h3>Review #1</h3>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce id sem libero. Duis sit amet pretium sapien.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="leftReview">
    <h3>Review #2</h3>

    <p>Nam ut nunc id turpis consequat vestibulum eget sit amet arcu. Nullam nec pellentesque leo, eu pulvinar velit.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="leftReview">
    <h3>Review #3</h3>

    <p>Pellentesque sagittis justo sit amet odio commodo, in malesuada nulla elementum. Integer pretium, sem nec vehicula dapibus.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="leftReview">
    <h3>Review #4</h3>

    <p>Arcu elit scelerisque enim, vel tincidunt velit ex non dolor. Proin nec fringilla mi. Nunc commodo nulla vitae ipsum eleifend fermentum.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To randomize the `div`s you need to use [`Math.random`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) function to get a random number.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(rotate,1200);
})
         
var panels = $('.leftReview');
var arr = [];
var rand = getRandom(panels.length);
panels.eq(rand).fadeIn();

function rotate() {
  var visible = panels.filter(':visible').fadeOut(function() {
    panels.eq(getRandom(panels.length)).fadeIn();
  });
}


function getRandom(length) {
  if (arr.length == length) {
    arr = [];
  }
  
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
  if (arr.indexOf(rand) > -1) {
    return getRandom(length)
  }

  arr.push(rand)
  return rand;
}
```

```css
#ReviewContainer{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;

}

.leftReview {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ReviewContainer">
  <div class="leftReview">
    <h3>Review #1</h3>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce id sem libero. Duis sit amet pretium sapien.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="leftReview">
    <h3>Review #2</h3>

    <p>Nam ut nunc id turpis consequat vestibulum eget sit amet arcu. Nullam nec pellentesque leo, eu pulvinar velit.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="leftReview">
    <h3>Review #3</h3>

    <p>Pellentesque sagittis justo sit amet odio commodo, in malesuada nulla elementum. Integer pretium, sem nec vehicula dapibus.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="leftReview">
    <h3>Review #4</h3>

    <p>Arcu elit scelerisque enim, vel tincidunt velit ex non dolor. Proin nec fringilla mi. Nunc commodo nulla vitae ipsum eleifend fermentum.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/pojoke/edit?html,css,js

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very much appreciated!

Comment: I just was updated my answer. Now it's support random **and show the all 4 then randomize again the 4 and so on**

Comment: Great job! Thank you!
I'm changing this to the best answer sorry Frank, but no worries I upvoted your correct answers to make up for it. ^^

Answer (score 2):

For make this, use `setInterval` event and make your div on `display:none` first

**Please try**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 0;
  var carrousel = setInterval(rotate,1200);
  
  function rotate(){
    if(id != $('.leftReview').length){
       $('.leftReview').eq(id).fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut(100)
       id++;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#ReviewContainer{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  
  }
  
 .leftReview{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
        display:none
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ReviewContainer">
         <div class="leftReview">
         <h3>Review #1</h3>
         
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce id sem libero. Duis sit amet pretium sapien.</p>
         </div>
         
         <div class="leftReview">
         <h3>Review #2</h3>
         
         <p>Nam ut nunc id turpis consequat vestibulum eget sit amet arcu. Nullam nec pellentesque leo, eu pulvinar velit.</p>
         </div>
         
         <div class="leftReview">
         <h3>Review #3</h3>
         
         <p>Pellentesque sagittis justo sit amet odio commodo, in malesuada nulla elementum. Integer pretium, sem nec vehicula dapibus.</p>
         </div>
         
         <div class="leftReview">
         <h3>Review #4</h3>
         
         <p>Arcu elit scelerisque enim, vel tincidunt velit ex non dolor. Proin nec fringilla mi. Nunc commodo nulla vitae ipsum eleifend fermentum.</p>
         </div>
         
</div>
```

**Update with random view**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var carrousel = setInterval(rotate,1200);
  
  function rotate(){
    id = Math.floor((Math.random() * $(".leftReview").length)); 
    $('.leftReview').eq(id).fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut(100)
  }
})
```

```css
#ReviewContainer{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  
  }
  
 .leftReview{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
        display:none
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ReviewContainer">
         <div class="leftReview">
         <h3>Review #1</h3>
         
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce id sem libero. Duis sit amet pretium sapien.</p>
         </div>
         
         <div class="leftReview">
         <h3>Review #2</h3>
         
         <p>Nam ut nunc id turpis consequat vestibulum eget sit amet arcu. Nullam nec pellentesque leo, eu pulvinar velit.</p>
         </div>
         
         <div class="leftReview">
         <h3>Review #3</h3>
         
         <p>Pellentesque sagittis justo sit amet odio commodo, in malesuada nulla elementum. Integer pretium, sem nec vehicula dapibus.</p>
         </div>
         
         <div class="leftReview">
         <h3>Review #4</h3>
         
         <p>Arcu elit scelerisque enim, vel tincidunt velit ex non dolor. Proin nec fringilla mi. Nunc commodo nulla vitae ipsum eleifend fermentum.</p>
         </div>
         
</div>
```

Comment: This is cool, but it doesn't loop and it's not randomized, sadly! But thank you nonetheless.

Comment: In the snippet the setInterval work fine and loop fine. But what is your browser? and have you an error in your debugger?

Comment: This is great! If only there was an option to make sure the same number can't play twice in a row... Or before the entire thing is looped, preferably. Is that possible too? Thnaks by the way, you're getting my check in advance! ^^

Comment: Mosh Fue, your answer does the same thing. Just now in my test it did 2 1 2 4 1 2. The best thing would be if it did all 4 before using the same number again. It's true your answer won't give you the same one twice in a row, though.